# jboss start up with clustering works in one order not the other

Tags: jboss, startup, cluster-computing

I have two clustered jboss nodes for this example I will call them A and B.

If i start node B first and then node A everything works fine and the servers start up in <45 seconds.  If I switch the order I have problems.  First problem is that it takes Node B FOREVER (like 5 minutes) to get past the [service] Removing bootstrap log handlers.  When it finally continues on it gets to the setting the clustered beans to the HA JNDI and it takes 1-2 minutes ber bean.  Meanwhile on node A I continously get
ERROR [org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.clustered.ClusteredDeploymentRepository] getModifiedDeployments() Cannot acquire local lock and then line above says Unable to acquire lock as it is held by Node B]

Any help is greatly appreciated.